# Devise root - disable must sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Whenever I access my home page or root, I'm redirected to Devise's /users/sign_in/. I've played with the routes.rb file a fair amount and I'm unable to figure out why Devise kicks in for the pages controller. The Pages controller is effectively empty.

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  root 'pages#index'
  resources :events do
    member do
      get :create_attendee
      delete :destroy_attendee
    end
  end

  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'events#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'pages#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

### pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]` to your `pages_controller.rb` and it'll skip the auth.

The `authenticate_user!` action is triggered for all controller method calls except `index`, i.e, for `create`, `update`... That way, you don't to go through log in page.

Comment: Does devise impact all controllers? Trying to figure out how Devise interacts with the Pages Controller.

Comment: Most likely, your Pages controller is a child of Application controller and that one has a filter which triggers devise.

Comment: The side effect here is that index calls for every controller are now open to anyone.